Too much clickable space around checkbox
I'm building a to-do list website and for some reason all the tasks created have too much space around the checkbox. screenshot of the tasks added.
I tried styling the checkbox to have 0 padding, 0 margin, changing the justify-content and align-items of the task but nothing seems to work. Here's the html, relevant part of css and javascript:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>task-ify - by livia</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h2 id="website-title">task-ify</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="screen">
            <form>
                <p id="newtask">new task</p>
                <input type="text" id="task" maxlength="27">
                <button type="button" id="savebttn" onclick="saveTask()">save</button>
            </form>
            <div class="todofield">
                <nav>
                    <p>filters:</p>
                    <button type="button" id="filter" onclick="viewAll()">ALL</button>
                    <button type="button" id="filter" onclick="viewToDo()">TO-DO</button>
                    <button type="button" id="filter" onclick="viewDone()">DONE</button>
                </nav>
                <div class="taskgallery" id="taskgallery">
                    <div class="taskview" id="taskview">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer><p>made by livia&copy;</p></footer>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

.taskgallery{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 0.1em solid #49311d;
    width: 90%;
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 3em;
    padding: 20px;
}

.taskview{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
    gap: 1.5vw 3vw;
}

#task1{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 30%;
    height: 5%;
    align-content: center;
}

#task1 > label{
    margin: 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 95%;
    align-content: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 1.8vh;
    color: #0A0903;
    background-color: #feaf55;
}

input [type="checkbox"]{
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;

}

function saveTask(){
    const newTask = document.getElementById('task');

    if(newTask.value != ''){
        const task = document.createElement('div');
        task.className = 'task';
        task.id = 'task1'

        const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';

        const label = document.createElement('label');
        label.textContent = newTask.value;
        
        //task.classList.add('to-do');

        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                label.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
                task.classList.remove('to-do');
                task.classList.add('done'); 
            } else {
                label.style.textDecoration = 'none';  
                task.classList.remove('done');
                task.classList.add('to-do'); 
            }
        });

        task.appendChild(checkbox);
        task.appendChild(label);

        document.getElementById('taskview').appendChild(task);
        tasks.push(task);
        newTask.value = '';
    }
}


Your above code doesn't have that problem you have shown in the screenshot. May be you are using another library that you didn't include in the code.

Really? Because I swear the problem is there, I even tried using different browsers to see if it was just on Opera gx but it happened on Chrome and Edge too. And I'm not using any library in this because my assignment doesn't allow it.

In general, you can use the DOM inspector (part of devtools) to diagnose where extra space is coming from.

Probably typo: there should be no space between input and [type...] part:
input[type="checkbox"] then all the paddings and margins inside that block apply correctly :) the space which still is there it's margin from #task1 > label {}.
Attached working snippet below


const tasks = [];
function saveTask(){
  const newTask = document.getElementById('task');

  if(newTask.value != ''){
      const task = document.createElement('div');
      task.className = 'task';
      task.id = 'task1'

      const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
      checkbox.type = 'checkbox';

      const label = document.createElement('label');
      label.textContent = newTask.value;
      
      //task.classList.add('to-do');

      checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
          if (this.checked) {
              label.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
              task.classList.remove('to-do');
              task.classList.add('done'); 
          } else {
              label.style.textDecoration = 'none';  
              task.classList.remove('done');
              task.classList.add('to-do'); 
          }
      });

      task.appendChild(checkbox);
      task.appendChild(label);

      document.getElementById('taskview').appendChild(task);
      tasks.push(task);
      newTask.value = '';
  }
}
.taskgallery {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 0.1em solid #49311d;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 3em;
  padding: 20px;
}

.taskview {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  gap: 1.5vw 3vw;
}

#task1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 30%;
  height: 5%;
  align-content: center;
}

#task1 > label {
  margin: 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  align-content: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.8vh;
  color: #0a0903;
  background-color: #feaf55;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>task-ify - by livia</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h2 id="website-title">task-ify</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="screen">
      <form>
        <p id="newtask">new task</p>
        <input type="text" id="task" maxlength="27" />
        <button type="button" id="savebttn" onclick="saveTask()">save</button>
      </form>
      <div class="todofield">
        <nav>
          <p>filters:</p>
          <button type="button" id="filter" onclick="viewAll()">ALL</button>
          <button type="button" id="filter" onclick="viewToDo()">TO-DO</button>
          <button type="button" id="filter" onclick="viewDone()">DONE</button>
        </nav>
        <div class="taskgallery" id="taskgallery">
          <div class="taskview" id="taskview"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer><p>made by livia&copy;</p></footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>




this worked perfectly!! thank you so much.
